# how to drop a rectangle?

Tags: swing, awt, java-2d

I need some help with my Java code. My code allows the rectangle follow where exactly the mouse icon go, but I want to make the rectangle stop at the position where I clicked on the drawing panel by mouse. How to make that happen? Can anyone help me?

Here's my code:

### Drawing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Drawing extends JFrame
{
    public Drawing()
    {}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.setBackground(Color.white);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(800, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

### Panel

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements  MouseMotionListener
    {   
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int width=200;
        int height=200;

        public Panel()
        {
            addMouseMotionListener(this);       
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){}    
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
        {
            x = e.getX() - 75;
            y = e.getY() -75;
            repaint();
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    }
```

Comment: It seems to be that you need to move (redraw) the rectangle when mouse button is pressed and the pointer is inside the rectangle.

Comment: @hfontanez Ya, I know but i have no idea how to do that

Comment: trial and error.  Copy the code inside `mouseMoved()` to the `mousePressed()` method and see what happens. Maybe all you have to do is to grab the (X,Y) of the rectangle on `mousePressed` and only `repaint` on `mouseMoved`. Since the `mousePressed` action precedes `mouseReleased`,  you don't have to do anything when it is released; but it will give the impression that you "dropped" the rectangle at that point.  What you don't want is to used the `mouseClicked` for this. Check out this [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: Remember one detail: an event-driven application reacts to events individually. This means, you can have simultaneous events (i.e. mouse button pressed and mouse moving) and the independent threads are able to do separate tasks without worrying what the other activity is doing (of course, in theory). Think about what task you want to accomplish while the mouse is moving (i.e. repainting the drawing if the current coordinates are within the rectangle) and what you want to accomplish when the button is pressed (i.e. get the coordinates and save them). **HINT:** how about using `mouseDragged`?

Comment: @hfontanez: I want to drag the rectangle without pressing the mouse, and I wanna drop the rectangle on the position mouse clicked .

Comment: In that case, you only need to handle two events: mouse moved and mouse clicked. Previous advise still applies: Divide and conquer. Think about what action needs to take place after each event. On mouse move, if the pointer is inside the component, repaint the component. There is, however, a slight flaw with this design: When you click the mouse button, the pointer will most likely be inside the rectangle, so that action listener will be triggered, causing the rectangle to keep on moving when you move the mouse; which is why I suggested using `mouseDragged` instead of `mouseMoved`.

Comment: @hfontanez : oic!!That is the reason why I can't drop the rectangle. My lecturer wont be pleased if I used mouseDragged

Answer (score 1):

Your class Panel should implement MouseListener interface and call addMouseListener method to be able to use mousePressed method; to stop moving your panel use a boolean which changes state when you press your mouse button, change your panel class to the following code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int width = 200;
    int height = 200;
    boolean move = true;

    public Panel() {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (move) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        move = !move;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if (move) {
            x = e.getX() - 75;
            y = e.getY() - 75;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```